# から ending a sentence

Tags: grammar, words, conjunctions

I've seen this in a few texts now and since it's appeared with some frequency I thought to post the question here. I tried searching online but came up with no real conclusions.

ありませんから or plain form ないから

I understand the ありません / ない, what is a little vague to me is the addition of から at the end.

I've included a sample sentence to add some context.

まだまだ中に戻る気はありませんからね。

Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: If you have the previous sentence as well, I think you should edit it in.

Answer (score 5):

Your sentence basically means "It's because I have no will/desire to go back inside yet."  The `から` is just stating that the preceding clause is a/the reason for some action/behaviour/etc.  However, due to your post, we don't know what that is.

An example might be the following:

> しょう君、なぜこの３時間ずっと外で遊んでいるの？　→　Hey Sho, why have you been playing outside for 3 hours?
>   まだまだ中に戻る気はありませんからね。　→　Because I don't want to go back inside yet, ね。

Comment: I think it'd be more like 接続助詞「から」＝活用語の終止形につき、原因や理由を表すほか、 "終助詞に似た形で、強い主張や決意を表す" http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E#.E7.B5.82.E5.8A.A9.E8.A9.9E

Comment: After reading this answer, and going back to read the texts that caused my confusion, @chocolate, your answer is the one that fits the content, and the sentences I read this in now are more clear. Thank you.