# 〜ものだから　〜もの　～もん What are the differences?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

What is the connotation when using 〜ものだから　and 〜もの in a sentence? In my text, they state these examples:

The first set is 〜ものだから：

> 上着を脱いでもいいですか。　暑いものですから。
>
> Can I take my jacket off? I'm feeling a bit hot.
>
> 遅くなってごめん。　道路が混んでいたもんだから。
>
> I'm sorry I'm late. I got caught in a traffic jam.

The second set is 〜もの:

> パーティーには行かなかったよ。　知らなかったんだもの。
>
> I didn't go to the party, because I didn't know it was on.
>
> しょうがないよ。　子供なんだもん。
>
> It can't be helped. He's just a kid.

I was told that one is used more often to assert a reason or excuse for something being done, and the other for expressing feeling. Is this true?
Other than that, is there any defining line between the two examples?

EDIT: I removed the question about whether a form was meant for subjectivity or objectivity.

Comment: In what sense is "道路が混む" or "being caught in a traffic jam" subjective?

Comment: @sawa Isn't it up to opinion whether some area is 混んでいる or not? I'm not sure about nuances, but in English we can always argue whether some place is crowded/busy or not.

Comment: Somewhat related: See Chocolate's comment on [から ending a sentence](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5465/542)

Comment: @Chris If that is the case, then, isn't "being a kid" subjective as well? You can argue whether someone is a kid or not. Or, does you example refer to a "legal" adult/kid? Then, does that mean that your sentence has different meaning depending on the country/area?

Comment: @sawa Probably. I'm not too sure it is relevant whether the examples are objective / subjective anymore since that doesn't seem to be the difference between the two examples. These sentences are from 日本語総まとめN2 by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think ものですから/もんですから/もんだから/ものだから/だもの/だもん can all be used to state a reason or excuse. (暑い)ものですから sounds very polite and a bit feminine (and maybe elegant too). (暑い)ものですから sounds more polite than (暑い)もんですから. (暑い)もんですから doesn't sound feminine or masculine to me. (道が混んでいた)もんだから sounds more casual than (道が混んでいた)ものですから/もんですから. Hmm maybe ものだから sounds a bit more feminine than もんだから in casual conversation. I think ものだから is not used so often as もんだから.
So... you can rephrase them as 「上着(を)脱いでもいい？暑いもん(orの)だから。」(more casual than your example)「遅くなってすみません。道が混んでいたもの(orん)ですから。」(more polite than your example) 
I think (知らなかったん)だもの sounds a bit more feminine than (知らなかったん)だもん.
 You can also say;
知らなかったもん(sounds more casual and maybe a bit more blunt than 知らなかったんだもん)/
知らなかったもの(sounds a bit more feminine than 知らなかったもん)/
子どもなんだもの(sounds more feminine than 子どもなんだもん)/
子どもだもん(sounds a bit more blunt and maybe more childish than 子どもなんだもん).　
(BTW if you want to sound more elegant and feminine, you can say 「パーティには行きませんでしたわ。知らなかったんですもの。」「しかたありませんわ。子どもなんですもの。」)

Edit:
Wait... now I think you're asking if the first set (~ものだから) and the second set (~だもの) are interchangeable, and how these two differ from each other...? 
1「上着、脱いでもいい？暑いんだもの/暑いんだもん」
2「遅くなってごめん。道が混んでいたんだもん」
3-a「パーティーには行かなかったよ。知らなかったもんだから。」
  b「パーティーには行きませんでした。知らなかったものですから。」
4-a「しょうがありません。子供なものですから。」
b「しょうがないよ。子どもなもんだから」
1 sounds fine to me, but I would rather say 「上着、脱ぐわ。(だって)暑いんだもん。」2 also sounds fine but I think it sounds like someone's blaming you for being late and you're stating an excuse. 3 sounds fine too. 4 sounds a bit awkward to me... I think you'd say 子どもなものですから/子どもなもんだから when you apologize to someone for something your kid has done. e.g. 「申し訳ありません、子どもなものですから」「ごめんね、子どもなもんだから」. 
So... I think the first set (~ものだから/もんだから) are more used to just express a reason, while the second set (~だもの/だもん) might have a nuance of complaint or dissatisfaction, a grumbling tone or maybe a criticizing tone... so the second set might sound like 'I didn't go to the party, and it wasn't my fault, because I wasn't invited/nobody told me about it.'/'It can't be helped, and you shouldn't complain, because he's just a kid.'