# What does 「ものさ」 mean here?

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

In Miffy - 日本語 [あめの　ひの　わすれもの!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PiLD51xZqD0) at around 5:14

Miffy with her family planned to go to the beach and before they started play, Uncle said:

「おじいちゃんの子どもの頃は砂浜でお城を作って遊んだ**ものさ**。」

[Weblio辞書](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE) says:

`活用語の終止形に付く。多く「だって」「でも」と呼応して用いる。現代では多く女性や子供の間で使われるが、時に撥音化して「もん」となることもある。`

But it's not used by women or children here, but by uncle, what does 「ものさ」 mean here?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69155  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5648

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43083/9831 (See `父は以前はバスで仕事に行ったものだ` `#4) Recollection and reminiscence.`)

Comment: @cats Please try to avoid answering questions in the comment section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you are looking at a wrong definition.

I suppose you are referring to this one under the 終助詞 (final particle) section in [the entry](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE):

> **１** 活用語の終止形に付く。多く「だって」「でも」と呼応して用いる。現代では多く女性や子供の間で使われるが、時に撥音化して「もん」となることもある。

But the correct one is under 名詞 (noun) which is way below:

> **５** 他の語句を受けて、その語句の内容を体言化する形式名詞。
> 　⋮
> ㋓（「…したものだ」の形で）過去を思い出してなつかしむ気持ちを示す。「あの店にはよく二人で行った物だ」

So the basic construction is the following.

> お城を作って遊んだものだ
> *I used to build castles for fun.*

And it seems to be rarely taught, but there are final particles that hides the copula だ and those not. さ is the former, that's why you don't see だ in that sentence.