# what's the meaning of だもん

Tags: grammar, meaning, colloquial-language, anime

Yamato and Takeo are discussing why their friend Suna is acting strange lately and Yamato suggests that Suna may be lonely.

I heard this expression a lot lately and was wondering what it could mean.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you learned もの yet?

Comment: I looked at the grammar point but didn't quite get the gist of it. Especially in this context

Comment: I think もん here either indicates an exclamation or conviction.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/69174/5010

Comment: だもん is a colloquial variant of だから(because) or "I will definitely do," or whatever completely depending on the context in question.