# How do you use もの?

Tags: translation, nominalization

I'm not very familiar with もの and have never been able to understand it well. I came across this phrase recently:

> 付き合い悪いもんあいつ

Why was もの used?

Comment: It's a particle, in case you aren't aware. [〜ものだから 〜もの ～もん What are the differences?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5648)